# How to listen approval of Pull request event by jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

we set the CI/CD pipeline , where user need to raise Pull Request, after which jenkins pull the PR and trigger building process followed by automation.

Now issue is as soon as user creates the PR, that PR need to be reviewed by some dev and needs to get approve before jenkin pulls it for further building process, which is currently not happening.

So how to make jenkins to listen to approve PR event of git, so that Jenkin do not pick the PR for processing unless PR is reviewed and approve by any other dev.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "GitHub Pull Request Builder plugin"
It has option "**Trigger Phrase**" where you can write Regex like "*Approved*". This will ensure to trigger the job when someone put "Approved" in the comments of the Pull request close. See some reference in below link on using Regex in "Trigger Phrase"

https://medium.com/@mreigen/integrate-jenkins-builds-into-github-pull-requests-33bc053d6210

Comment: But its getting trigger even with raise of Pull Request, use case is i just want to trigger job when PR is approved.

Comment: Also, whenever i am commenting on PR, its getting trigger. I need to trigger when it is APPROVED by any reviewer.